# Solving an identified integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to integrate the following expression,

### f(t)= l*exp((m+1)*t-c1*exp(-t))

but I can not get this to solve using the code below:

```
c1=1;
m=1;
l=1;
syms t
fun=l*exp((m+1)*t-c1*exp(-t));
g=int(fun,t);
```

Does any one have any idea which results are correct?

Comment: You are mixing symbolic integration and numerical integration. `integral` is for numerical integration. Use `int` for symbolic ones. (Although I don't think you will good results. What is your application?)

Comment: @ Argyll, Thank you for your comment. I also think that the result is not well. I want to study this integral in a specific equation accrues in a dynamic system.

Comment: I could be wrong but I remember exponential of exponential are one of the types of integrals where you cannot find analytical solutions.

Comment: @ Argyll, Yes, I think you are right, and maybe, it is the reason why this problem happens.

Comment: If you are able to obtain a result in matlab with valid format, but wonder whether the result is correct, after plotting the functions and inspecting their features together, you best bet is to compare to other symbolic computation tools such as mathematica and maple. Afterwards, you can post a question on math.stackexchange or math.stackoverflow . Here, we only deal with programming issue. I feel the appropriate answer lies in my first comment.

Comment: @ Argyll, Yes, of course, I will do this.

Comment: @Argyll, In addition, I should mention that I could get the result with the following commands, but I really do not know whether these results are correct or not?

c1=1;m=1;l=1;
syms t
gg=l*exp((m+1)*t-c1*exp(-t));
g=int(gg,t,[1 2]);
gVpa=vpa(g);

It seems I should do the things what you said.